# <WINDOWS> Eclipse developer suddenly not recognising HTC One M8

Tags: android, eclipse, device

After finally getting around to my Android Development course again, and finishing assignment no.1, I ran into an issue.
Where first Eclipse would recognise my device on the fly, it suddenly didn't anymore. Instead, the Eclipse Device Manager kept on adding devices like this every second:

- Serial number   : SH43TWM06516
- AVD Name        : "N/A"
- Target          : Unknown
- Debug           :
- State           : Offline

After about 30 seconds (That's 30 'devices'), adb.exe crashes en restarts itself automatically, even if Eclipse is not open.

I have tried:

- Turning off my USB Debug and then On again
- Unplugging my phone and then back in again
- opened the command-console, *adb.exe devices*, *adb.exe kill-server*, *adb.exe start-server*
- Shut down eclipse, killing adb.exe through the task manager, reboot eclipse
- Reinstalled all drivers/packages
- Reboot my laptop
- Reboot my phone
- Checked for updates (manually too)
- Start a new Project
- Reinstalled Eclipse
- Deleted the .android folder in my *User* directory
- Googled for help
- Try a different USB port
- Try a different USB cable

So now I'm here, kind of running out of options after 4 hours of toiling like a madman.
I hope someone here can help me with this issue.

=Edit=
Forgot to add:

- Developing in Eclipse Juno
- Using SDK platform-tools 20
- Android 4.4 (API 20)
- Google USB Driver

-Zubaja

Comment: you have not prayed yet? it was a joke... this behaviour is pretty weird. it sounds like a hardware issue, but it is difficult to guess what is happening here...

Comment: I have tried sacrificing my laptop to Satan.
Another thing I've read is to try a USB 2.0 port. Shame my laptop only has 3.0 ports. Might have to switch to my desktop if that's the case.

Comment: USB 3.0 is fully compatible with USB 2.0, it must not be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to fix my problem. I had to try a 3rd cable I had lying around. Same USB port, same phone, same everything; only difference was another different USB cable.

Comment: throw these two bad cables then. no, seriously, some cables are bad options for these purposes, take care about that. mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Such a weird way of solving a problem. Worked for me too though :D Upvote!